# How do I sync new additions to a folder without syncing the rest of the folder?

Tags: dropbox

I have a folder that is full of old client work (Client1, Client2 etc). This folder exists on my remote Dropbox, but not on my local machine, because I have removed this folder from Selective Sync:

```
Dropbox
- Clients
  - Client1
  - Client2
  ...
```

I'm now adding new client work (Client22) locally to the same folder. I would like to make sure that this new work gets **uploaded** to Dropbox:

```
Dropbox
- Clients
  - Client22
```

However, I don't want to **download** all the old client work, because it's far too many files to sync, and I don't need it locally.

If I go to Selective Sync and look at the checkboxes, I see checkboxes for Client1, Client2, etc, but not for Client22.

So (given that I can't check this checkbox), how can I make sure that this folder gets uploaded to Dropbox?

Comment: Just upload the folder manually using drag-n-drop instead of syncing?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this via the filesystem of your local machine, because the subdirectory (Clients) on which you want to drop the new stuff (Client22) for Dropbox upload, is not synced by Dropbox.

Therefore you need to log in to the Dropbox web interface and upload the Client22 folder from there, using the Upload button.